# The Class of Finitely Generated Groups Can Be Axiomatized in $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1 \omega}$

Tags: proof-verification, logic

I am studying Ebbinghaus book "Mathematical Logic". In the chapter regarding "Extensions of First-Order Logic", I am trying to solve the following question (only letter (a)), and I would like to ask you if my attempt is correct.

> **2.8 Exercise.** Show that the following classes can be axiomatized by an  $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1 \omega}$ sentence:
>
> (a) - the class of finitely generated groups;
>
> (b) - the class of structures isomorphic to ($\mathbb{Z}$, $\lt$).

I am trying to solve letter (a). Here's what I have tried:

The sentence $\Phi_{gr} \land \Psi$, shows the class of finitely generated groups is axiomatizable, where $\Phi_{gr}$ is a sentence to represent the group axioms and $\Psi$ is a sentence that says the group is finitely generated by saying "the group is 1-generated OR the group is 2-generated OR ...":

> $\Psi := \bigvee \{ \psi_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Here $\psi_n$ is a sentence that says that the group is $n$-generated:

> $\psi_n := \exists y_1 \ldots \exists y_n \forall x \ ( x \equiv y_{i_1} \ldots y_{i_k})$, where each one of the $y_{i_1}, \ldots, y_{i_k}$ is $y_1$ or $y_{1}^{-1}$ or $\ldots$ or $y_n$ or $y_{n}^{-1}$.

Can anyone tell me if what I did is correct and/or if there is a better way to write it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexKruckman You are right. We need infinitary disjunction for $x=...$ part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the idea is correct, but of course you haven't actually expressed $\psi_n$ as a sentence of $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ (the "where each..." clause is crucial to the meaning, and expresses an infinite disjunction). To be more precise, you could write $$\psi_n := \exists y_1\dots \exists y_n\forall x \bigvee_{w\in W_n} (x = w)$$
where $W_n$ is the set of all group terms in the variables $y_1,\dots, y_n$.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that to express the "where each" clause I would need an infinite disjunction.